# QGIS Field Calculator - Remove text inside multipe parentheses from a string

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, regular-expression

On the QGIS Field calculator, I am trying to remove from a string the text that is inside parentheses using `regexp_replace`.

While it is not a problem to remove the text from a string that contains only one parentheses group (using

```
regexp_replace('Steep (61° to 84°)','[(](.*)?[)]','')
```

it gives "Steep" as a result.

I am having some issues with extracting the text from a string where are present multiple parentheses, e.g.,

'Steep (61° to 84°), Vertical / Near Vertical (85° to 90°)'

From the above string, I would like to obtain

'Steep, Vertical / Near Vertical'

but if I try to use the same regex I obtain again only "steep", because for the system the closing parenthesis is the one at the end of the string.

Comment: What happens when you run your `regexp_replace()` on the whole string?

Comment: Hi, the result is the same as the previous: `steep `, because for the expression the last ) is at the end of the string.

Comment: Have you tried running the `regexp_replace()` on substrings, which you define by whether they are before or after the comma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can expand your group to include the `[(]` and `[)]` by moving the inner parentheses outwards, like so:

```sql
'([(].*?[)])'
```

The expression becomes:

```sql
regexp_replace('Steep (61° to 84°), Vertical / Near Vertical (85° to 90°)','([(].*?[)])','')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It solves my issue.

Comment: Glad to help. There is a trailing space after `Steep` but it should be fairly simple to remove if you need to.

Comment: Prefixing the pattern with a space seems to do the trick: `' ([(].*?[)])'`

Comment: I was using a simple `replace(xxx, ' ,',',')` but this is definitely a better solution. Thanks again.

Comment: As long as the data is formatted consistently for every row, with both sets of parentheses having a space before them. Otherwise, your method might be safer :)

Answer (score 6):

With this expression also take into account the space after Steep:

```
regexp_replace(
  'Steep (61° to 84°), Vertical / Near Vertical (85° to 90°)',
  ' \\(\\d+° to \\d+°\\)','')
```

[image]